# How to split a large folder into smaller folders of equal size

Tags: files, directory, split, size

I have one big folder with many file types in it (e.g `.txt`, `.sh`). It's about 40Gb. I would like to split it into four parts of 10Gb each. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Any try so far?

Comment: I don't suppose you have any individual files larger than 10 Gb?

Comment: take a look at split command maybe ?

Comment: Do you need to access the files, or is it for archiving? One could use multi volume archive format.

Comment: Why is this closed? It's perfectly clear what they're asking.

Answer (score 7):

Without trying to solve the [bin packing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem), you could use a script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                     
directory=${1:-testdir}                                                         
sizelimit=${2:-1000} # in MB                                                    
sizesofar=0                                                                     
dircount=1                                                                      
du -s --block-size=1M "$directory"/* | while read -r size file                  
do                                                                              
  if ((sizesofar + size > sizelimit))                                           
  then                                                                          
    (( dircount++ ))                                                            
    sizesofar=0                                                                 
  fi                                                                            
  (( sizesofar += size ))                                                       
  mkdir -p -- "$directory/sub_$dircount"                                           
  mv -- "$file" "$directory/sub_$dircount"                                           
done
```

Comment: If the files are small it might be better to use kb or byte resolution but besides that +1 for the script and mentioning the optimization problem.

Comment: Awesome script - well done, perfect for what I needed ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If it is a single 10GB file, you can try

```
split -b 4000000000 filename
```

Comment: Note, the user does not want to split the files themselves, but to distribute them evenly between subfolders.

Comment: ... I think....

Comment: Not sure, myself, but the title does go in the direction of directories: "split a large folder into smaller folders of equal size".