# How to Split a Large Directory By Size?

Tags: bash

I have one directory that is about 2.5 TB in size. Inside this directory, there over 3000 subdirectories and no files. Each of these subdirectories varies in size greatly, some under 1 MB and some over 15 GB, but none of them exceeds 20 GB. I want to split this main directory into many smaller ones, each under 20 GB. This solution **does not** need to mid-max the storage, meaning, it can just sort all files alphabetically and add directories as long as it doesn't exceed 20 GB.

I have already tried the answer on [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/490124/how-to-split-a-large-folder-into-smaller-folders-of-equal-size) solution, and although it works great for directories containing files, it doesn't work in the case where there are subdirectories.

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                     
directory=${1:-testdir}                                                         
sizelimit=${2:-1000} # in MB                                                    
sizesofar=0                                                                     
dircount=1                                                                      
du -s --block-size=1M "$directory"/* | while read -r size file                  
do                                                                              
  if ((sizesofar + size > sizelimit))                                           
  then                                                                          
    (( dircount++ ))                                                            
    sizesofar=0                                                                 
  fi                                                                            
  (( sizesofar += size ))                                                       
  mkdir -p -- "$directory/sub_$dircount"                                           
  mv -- "$file" "$directory/sub_$dircount"                                           
done
```

Comment: [`datapacker`](http://jgoerzen.github.io/datapacker/datapacker.html) maybe. I have never used it but the manual looks promising.

Comment: what do you mean by "it doesn't work"?   `du -s` works just as well on sub-directories as it does on files.

Comment: I'm not experienced in Bash scripting, but I've tried it before. For some reason, it only works with files (not directories). It just ignores the sub-directories I want to move and creates empty directories. Try it if you want.

Comment: EDIT: I'm not sure how it happened, but last time I tried this script, it didn't work for folders. Now I tried it and it works, even though not so efficiently.